# PAYPAL IPN Call responds with Status Retrying and HTTP-Code 404

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to set up a notification from on a payment. Here is my code:

```
def PayPal_IPN():
   
    '''This module processes PayPal Instant Payment Notification messages (IPNs).'''

    # Switch as appropriate
    VERIFY_URL_PROD = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'
    VERIFY_URL = VERIFY_URL_PROD

    # Read and parse query string
    params = request.form.to_dict()

    # Add '_notify-validate' parameter
    params['cmd'] = '_notify-valudate'

    # Post back to PayPal for validation

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'user-agent': 'Python-IPN-Verification-Script'}
    r = requests.post(VERIFY_URL, params=params, headers=headers, verify=True)
    r.raise_for_status()

    # Check return message and take action as needed
    if r.text == 'VERIFIED':
        print("SUCCESSFULL")
    elif r.text == 'INVALID':
        print("FAILURE")
    else:
        print("NOTHING HAPPENED?")
    return ""
```

Here is my error message:
`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`....

Can someone help me figure out what I am not understanding? maybe the link has changed?

Here is the documentation I'm looking at https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNIntro/

I've tried changing the ipnpb to www. and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the format of `params`.  I'm not sure what `request.form.to_dict()` returns, but I do know that when you add cmd=_notify_validate it should be in this format:

```py
params.append(('cmd', '_notify-validate'))
```

Also returning the appropriate format is `urllib.parse.parse_qsl`